# How to create a new token.json file using gmail api?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, access-token

I'm working on Gmail API. I have a token.json file, in which I have an access token and refresh token. but there is an expiry for those values.
When It expires I need to run the application and they will provide me a link to need permission from my Gmail account. and after giving permission they will provide a key which we have to place in our terminal for getting a new token. But how can I create this new token file without doing this manually?
Is there any way to create this token.json file dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have run the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) sample of the Gmail API and you want to create a new `token.json` without waiting the expiration time. In order to achieve this, you can modifiy the function `authorize` in the following way:

```js
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);

}
```

### update

The `token.json` will expire. I understood that you wanted to generate a new one in each run. If you want it not to expire, I recommend you read the [notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs#notes) of the `Quickstart`.

> The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command line application. For information on how to perform authorization in other contexts, see the [Authorizing and Authenticating](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#authorizing-and-authenticating). section of the library's README.

Here you can find different ways to authenticate Google APIs, which meet your requirement. I recommend you read [OAuth2](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client) and [Service account credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials).

Comment: okay, by using this function the token.json file will not expire?

Comment: By modifying authorize function the token.json file still expired and when I run my application I got a link for a new token which I have to give permission from Gmail.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it helps you